# How to center a div horizontally and vertically using flex?

Tags: html, css

how to center a div horizontaly and vertically using flexbox?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;` and put it in the container.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```